# Flutter 'Packages get' failed after adding firebase dependency

Tags: firebase, flutter

I am trying to add Firebase to my flutter app. But when I add firebase_core dependency in the pubspec_yaml and run Packages get, it gives an error.

```
19-----dependencies:
20-----flutter:
21-----sdk: flutter
22-----firebase_core: ^0.2.5
```

This is the code that gives the error.

The output of Packages get :

```
C:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat --no-color packages get
Running "flutter packages get" in trial_one...                  
Error on line 21, column 5 of pubspec.yaml: A dependency may only have one source.
sdk: flutter
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


pub get failed (65)
Process finished with exit code 65
```

I followed the exact instructions on the [Add Firebase to Flutter](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup#add_flutterfire_plugins) site. But still I get this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The indentation is actually not good, here's the correct one :

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  firebase_core: ^0.3.1+1
```

Hope it's help !!

Comment: Thank you, it works fine now. If I want to add more packages, do I use the same indentation as   firebase_core: ^0.3.1+1 ?